# Is it possible to find the range of y-positions where I can draw a horizontal line between two squares?

Tags: geometry

My squares are defined in a coordinate grid where the origin is in the upper-left. My squares are defined with x,y,w,h (x position, y position, width, height).

For example, if we have two squares, where square1 is on the left of square2, and we know there is some range where they are on the same y-axis, can we find this range, given the x,y,w,h of both squares?

Comment: What is the difference between width and height?

Comment: width = x axis length
height =  y axis length

Comment: What do you mean by "My squares are defined with x,y,w,h" ? Is (x,y) the coordinate of the upper-left vertex ? Are your squares in fact **rectangles** with sides $w,h$ parallel to the $x$ and $y$ axes ?

Comment: No answer to my questions ?...